# Where is the bash feature to open a command in $EDITOR documented?

Tags: bash, line-editor

I have recently discovered that if we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, bash opens the current command in an editor (set in `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR`) and executes it when the editor is closed.

But it doesn't seem to be documented in the `man` pages.  Is it documented, and if so where?

Comment: Search for `edit-and-execute-command` in the man page.

Comment: If you use Bash's vi mode, the short cut is Esc, V. I trigger this all the time by accident. Finally learned what it means today :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have found it out now. I should have read it more carefully before asking this.

The `man` page says:

> ```
> edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
>           Invoke  an  editor  on the current command line, and execute the
>           result as shell commands.   Bash  attempts  to  invoke  $VISUAL,
>           $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.
> ```

Comment: Be very careful with this feature. If you cancel the edit, the original command line will be immediately executed. So if you are editing rm -rf / and invoke the editor and realize you are into something dangerous and thus cancel the edit, your rootfs will be deleted without further questions asked.

Comment: @marlar if your editor is vim, you can use `:cq`, it makes it exit with non-zero code, and prevents the command from execution

Comment: @marlar [ctrl-x-e without executing command immediately](https://superuser.com/q/1601543/432690).

Comment: @karlicoss Sure, :cq etc works if you are aware of it and remember it. But if you don't, shit can happen.

Comment: As an alternative (also if you remember it) just delete everything and change to `ls` then save & exit.

Comment: Or prefix with `#`

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments under the accepted answer, it is very convenient/safe to have an editor feature **without immediate execution**.

Add this to `.bashrc` to make <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd></kbd> binding disable execution.

```bsh
_edit_wo_executing() {
    local editor="${EDITOR:-nano}"
    tmpf="$(mktemp).sh"
    printf '%s\n' "$READLINE_LINE" > "$tmpf"
    $editor "$tmpf"
    READLINE_LINE="$(<"$tmpf")"
    READLINE_POINT="${#READLINE_LINE}"
    rm "$tmpf"
}

bind -x '"\C-x\C-e":_edit_wo_executing'
```

Credits: https://superuser.com/a/1601690/266871