# How to perform substitution with vim in the current command-line command?

Tags: command-line, vim

I use vim on the command line. I want to use the substitution command to search for and replace characters in the command line I’m currently working on in the CLI.

Here’s merely one example, say I want to rename a file and begin writing a command like so:

```
mv here_is_a_way_too_long_filename.txt here_is_a_way_too_long_filename.txt
```

The filename is very long, so for convenience I’ve used tab completion to produce the second filename. Now I want to replace the underscores with something else, for example `\` .

I’m using vim in the CLI, so I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to enter (vim) normal mode, go to the start of the second filename, and then press `:` to enter the command `s/_/\ /`. FYI, after entering the `:` here, I’m seeing this:

```
mv here_is_a_way_too_long_filename.txt here_is_a_way_too_long_filename.txt
execute: s/_/xxx/
```

→ *but* I cannot type a space *or* press return to execute this vim substitution command. In fact, I can only exit this extra `execute:` line by pressing `^C`.

I’ve also tried numerous variations of the substitution command, to no avail:

```
s/_/xxx/
gs/_/xxx/
%s/_/\\ /  ← NB: I can’t actually enter the space here.
s/_/\\s/
s/_/[:space:]/
... and so on
```

I don’t want to resort to the command history. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243317/) describes doing something similar but for a previous command in the command history.

What I want to end up with (in the above example) is this:

```
mv here_is_a_way_too_long_filename.txt here\ is\ a\ way\ too\ long\ filename.txt
```

after which I press enter to execute the `mv` command in the shell (eg. `zsh`).

I want to do this with vim in the CLI if possible. Notes on spaces in filenames are outside the scope; assume I’m aware of those perils.

Comment: FYI: You aren't actually using Vim there. You're using your shell's vi key bindings (or "vi mode"), which has some movement and basic editing shortcuts bound to Vim-like keys. That's about it for them. If you want to actually edit the current line in Vim, there are keybindings available for that in [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85393/70524) and [zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6622/70524). Here, when you press `:`, you're just entering Zsh's command mode, where you can enter [ZLE commands](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html), *not* Vim commands.